# Place AJAX .html(data) .after an element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having trouble figuring this out. I am making a jQuery Ajax call. I am trying to append the data after an element without creating an element to stick it into, if that makes any sense so for example trying to  do something like:

```
$('#load').after().html(data);
```

I know thats not right but hopefully you understand what I am trying to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try placing the Script block where you want the element and use document.write

Comment: thats not going to work out for me. The ajax call is wrapped in a function, and is called, by page scrolling.

Comment: What sort of data is coming back?  Raw html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass the data to after(), not assign it.

```
$('#load').after(data);
```